# How would I create a HTTPS request in vala?

Tags: vala

I am trying to create a github issue app in vala and need to get the list of issues from https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed.

I have tried using this example in my code but this is not working for SSL.
https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GIONetworkingSample

I have also tried soup but this seems to have a problem where it can't find its dev headers.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Soup is definitely the right way to do HTTP. On debian you need `libsoup2.4-dev` and `gir1.2-soup-2.4` packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the tls property to true on the SocketClient object, and
you have to connect to the correct port (443). This works for me:

```
var client = new SocketClient() { tls = true };
// Or do this (does the same):
// var client = new SocketClient();
// client.tls = true;
var socket = client.connect_to_host (hostname, 443);
```

If the server you are connecting to are using a self-signed certificate,
you also have to change the TLS validation flags:
client.set_tls_validation_flags (...);

But it's probably easier with Soup, as another commenter pointed out.

God luck. Vala is a sweet language.

Comment: Thanks guys after your advice I persisted with soup and got it working in the end.